# Unable to alter amd GPU and Mem clocks and voltages in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gpu, amdgpu

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I was no longer able to tweak my clock and voltage settings for my Sapphire Radeon RX 580 Pulse or for my Sapphire Radeon RX 580 Nitro+ SE.  The changing the fan and power limit presents no problem.  I'm using amdgpu driver 20.30-1109583.  I tried using amdgpu driver 20.20 but encountered the same problems.

I tried doing it manually, with a Bash script, with Wattman_GTK, with amdgpu-clocks, and attempted to use CoreCtrl (which crashes).

I had changed /etc/default/grub to include:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff"
```

and also tried

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff"
```

Here is my Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get path for card 1
card_path=`readlink -f /sys/class/drm/card1/device`

echo "Path for card: $card_path"
echo "Initial values for card:"
echo "Power limit: $(cat $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap)"
echo "Fan settings: $(cat $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1)"
pwm1_max=`cat $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1_max`
echo "pwm1_max: $pwm1_max"
echo "GPU and memory clocks and voltages"
echo "$(cat $card_path/power_dpm_force_performance_level)"
echo "$(cat $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage)"
echo " "

# Set power limit

echo "Setting card power limit:"
echo 101000000 > $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap

echo " "

# Set GPU and mem clocks and voltages

echo "Setting GPU and Mem clocks and voltages:"
echo manual > $card_path/power_dpm_force_performance_level

echo 's 0 300 750' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 1 751 793' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 2 848 806' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 3 858 812' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 4 900 820' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 5 1059 840' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 6 1194 880' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 's 7 1280 890' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage

echo 'm 0 300 750' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 'm 1 1000 800' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 'm 2 2215 895' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage

echo c > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage

# Set Fan
echo " "
echo "Setting Fan:"
echo 1 > $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1_enable
pwr_prc=$((pwm1_max * 7/10))
echo "$pwr_prc"
echo $pwr_prc > $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1



# Check values 

echo " "
echo "Check settings"
echo "Power limit: $(cat $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/power1_cap)"
echo " "
echo "Fan settings: $(cat $card_path/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1)"
echo " "
echo "Clocks and voltages: "
echo "$(cat $card_path/power_dpm_force_performance_level)"
echo "$(cat $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage)"
```

Running the script using

```
sudo sh -c ./card1.sh
```

yields:

```
Initial values for card:
Power limit: 101000000
Fan settings: 173
pwm1_max: 255
GPU and memory clocks and voltages
manual
OD_SCLK:
0:        300MHz        750mV
1:        751MHz        793mV
2:       1048MHz       1006mV
3:       1158MHz       1112mV
4:       1240MHz       1150mV
5:       1309MHz       1150mV
6:       1364MHz       1150mV
7:       1430MHz       1150mV
OD_MCLK:
0:        300MHz        750mV
1:       1000MHz        800mV
2:       2100MHz        950mV
OD_RANGE:
SCLK:     300MHz       2000MHz
MCLK:     300MHz       2250MHz
VDDC:     750mV        1200mV
 
Setting card power limit:
 
Setting GPU and Mem clocks and voltages:
./card1.sh: line 28: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 29: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 30: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 31: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 32: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 33: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 34: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 35: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 37: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 38: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 39: echo: write error: Invalid argument
./card1.sh: line 41: echo: write error: Invalid argument
 
Setting Fan:
178
 
Check settings
Power limit: 101000000
 
Fan settings: 173
 
Clocks and voltages: 
manual
OD_SCLK:
0:        300MHz        750mV
1:        751MHz        793mV
2:       1048MHz       1006mV
3:       1158MHz       1112mV
4:       1240MHz       1150mV
5:       1309MHz       1150mV
6:       1364MHz       1150mV
7:       1430MHz       1150mV
OD_MCLK:
0:        300MHz        750mV
1:       1000MHz        800mV
2:       2100MHz        950mV
OD_RANGE:
SCLK:     300MHz       2000MHz
MCLK:     300MHz       2250MHz
VDDC:     750mV        1200mV
```

Wattman_GTK and amdgpu-clocks also yielded the error:

```
write error: Invalid argument
```

Running the script using

```
$sudo sh card1.sh
```

gives, instead of "echo: write error: Invalid argument",

```
echo: echo: I/O error
```

This also happens when I attempt to change clocks and voltages from command line:

```
$sudo echo 's 7 1280 895' > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:0d:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

which yields:

```
-bash: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:0d:00.0/pp_od_clk_voltage: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with the default kernel (5.4).
After updating the kernel to the edge one (linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge), the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Radeon VII with 20.04 and driver 20.45

For all core clock levels change:

```
echo 's 0 300 750' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

to:

```
echo 'vc 0 300 750' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

and memory levels only get one setting for max frequency so delete:

```
echo 'm 0 300 750' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
echo 'm 1 1000 800' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

and change:

```
echo 'm 2 2215 895' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

to:

```
echo 'm 1 2215' > $card_path/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just changed double quotes (") to simple quotes (') and it worked fine

IE change:

```
echo "s 0 300 750" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

to:

```
echo 's 0 300 750' > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_od_clk_voltage
```

Hope this helps.